# ¿Cómo mostrar los elementos de un arreglo al azar?

Tags: javascript, html, array, reactjs, map

Tengo este arreglo:

```
let vengadores = [
    {nombre: "steve rogers", nombreHeroe: "captain america"},
    {nombre: "tony stark", nombreHeroe: "iron man"},
    {nombre: "bruce banner", nombreHeroe: "the hulk"},
    {nombre: "peter parker", nombreHeroe: "spiderman"},
    {nombre: "tchalla", nombreHeroe: "black panther"}
]
```

Y quiero mostrarlos en un html pero que cada ves que se recarge la pagina se muestren en una posición diferente, ejemplo:

```
<p>{vengador.nombre}</p> //steve rogers
<p>...</p>
```

Se recarga la pagina y ahora sale:

```
<p>{vengador.nombre}</p> //tchalla
<p>...</p>
```

Aparte de `vengadores.map`, que uso?

Comment: Debes "barajar" tu lista. Existen diversos métodos, siendo el [algoritmo de Fisher-Yates](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algoritmo_de_Fisher-Yates) uno de los más usados. Saludos

Answer (score -1):

Es usando este codigo:

```
vengadores.sort(()=> Math.random() - 0.5).map(item =>{
...
})
```

Comment: Solo por si te interesa,  esa solución que planteas es [SUPER INEFICIENTE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18650169/8838721). Tal vez para lo que necesitas está bien y puedes aceptarlo, pero si tienes arreglos más grandes, considera alguna de las otras alternativas que te dan en ese enlace para randomizar un arreglo.